# Checar apenas os não desabilitados

Tags: javascript, jquery

Possuo diversos checkbox que podem estar desabilitados ou não através do disabled na tag input.

Necessito que ao clicar no checkbox pai, apenas os NÃO desabilitados sejam habilitados ao invés de todos.

O problema:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A solução:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código até o momento que da checked em todos os checkboxs:

```
$("#checkAll").click(function () {
   $("input:checkbox").not(this).prop("checked", this.checked);
});
```

Como posso filtrar os não desabilitados para então dar checked?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Solução encontrada:

```
  $("#checkAll").change(function () {
       $("input:checkbox:not([disabled])").prop("checked", this.checked);
    });
```